# How do I upsample time series in tsdb

Tags: time-series, interpolation, opentsdb

I want to upsample a time series in OpenTSDB.  For example, suppose I have temperatures that are recorded at 8 hour intervals, e.g., at 1am, 9am and 5pm every day.  I want to retrieve by a TSDB query an upsampling of these data, so that I get temperatures at 1am, 2am, 3am, ...., 5pm, 6pm, ... midnight  I want the "missing" data to be filled in by linear interpolation, e.g.,

otemp(2am) = itemp(1am) + 1/8 * ( itemp(9am) - itemp(1am) )

where otemp is the output up-sampled result and itemp is the input time series.

The problem is that OpenTSDB only seems to be willing to linearly interpolate data in the context of a multi-time-series operation like "sum".  Now, I can kluge the solution that I want be creating another time series "ctemp" (the "c" is for "clock") that records a temperature of 0 every 1 hour, and then ask TSDB to give me the sum of this time-series with the itemp's.

Am I misunderstanding the OpenTSDB, and there is a way to do this without having to create the bogus "ctemp" series? Something reasonable like:

...?start=some_time&end=some_time&interval=1h&m=lerp:itemp

?
-- Mark

Answer (score 0):

For comparison with [Axibase TSD](http://axibase.com/products/axibase-time-series-database/) which runs on HBase, the interpolation can be performed using [`WITH INTERPOLATE`](https://axibase.com/docs/atsd/sql/#regularization) clause.

```
SELECT date_format(time, 'MMM-dd HH:mm') AS sample_time, 
  value 
FROM temperature 
  WHERE entity = 'sensor'
    AND datetime BETWEEN '2017-05-14T00:00:00Z' AND '2017-05-17T00:00:00Z'
  WITH INTERPOLATE(1 HOUR)
```

Sample commands:

```
series e:sensor d:2017-05-14T01:00:00Z m:temperature=25
series e:sensor d:2017-05-14T09:00:00Z m:temperature=30
series e:sensor d:2017-05-14T17:00:00Z m:temperature=29
series e:sensor d:2017-05-15T01:00:00Z m:temperature=28
series e:sensor d:2017-05-15T09:00:00Z m:temperature=35
series e:sensor d:2017-05-15T17:00:00Z m:temperature=31
series e:sensor d:2017-05-16T01:00:00Z m:temperature=22
series e:sensor d:2017-05-16T09:00:00Z m:temperature=40
series e:sensor d:2017-05-16T17:00:00Z m:temperature=33
```

[The result](https://apps.axibase.com/chartlab/b110fbe9):

```
sample_time     value
May-14 01:00    25.0000
May-14 02:00    25.6250
May-14 03:00    26.2500
May-14 04:00    26.8750
May-14 05:00    27.5000
...
```

[image: Interpolation]

Disclaimer: I work for Axibase.